# Define a dynamic angular function for ng-click in controller when using a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I define a function that executes on ng-click in a modal?

I tried this:

```
<a ng-click="action.func(attr);">{{action.name}}</a></li>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.attributeActions = [{name: 'remove', func: $scope.remove()}];
```

The remove function is executing onLoad of the modal form.

Comment: You want to bind ng-click to an element in a modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

In the form:

```
<li ng-repeat="action in attributeActions>
<a ng-click="execute(action.func, attr);">{{action.name}}</a></li>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.remove = function(attr) { 
    console.log('it worked', attr);
};

$scope.attributeActions = [{name: 'remove', func: $scope.remove}];

$scope.execute = function(fn, attr) {
    console.log('executing function', fn);
    fn(attr);
}
```